# Smartkey for Outlook

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

My smartphone app SwiftKey does a fantastic job of suggesting words as I type (predictive text). I want the same thing for Outlook 2010. Outlooks current autosuggest seems clunky in comparison. SwiftKey automatically learns the word I type and really cuts down on typing time.

Anyone know of anything similar for Outlook?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the on-screen keyboard in Windows 7?  What Windows software have you tried already?  Just asking for a list of software that does X is considered not constructive and/or off-topic, and may be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you have added the Windows 7 tag I'm assuming you're asking about Windows.
No there isn't something exactly like swiftkey for Windows. Windows does have a built in auto suggest feature but it isn't as good.

I've read about Co:Writer. I'm not sure how good or bad it is. but certainly you should check it out.
website: http://www.donjohnston.com/resources/cowriter6_index.html